# How does a webpage determine if/when something is viewed?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, browser, web

I'm seeking to understand the code and function(s) that determines when a particular part of a webpage has been viewed (for mere understanding).

For example, on the StackExchange websites, it determines when a person has fully read the "about" page (and awards a badge for such). What function/code/language is watching for this?

Or at least, how could I trace and/or determine where this function is in a page's source?

Comment: I am betting they are looking at the scroll position based on the height of the container.

Comment: @epascarello yes, exactly... and probably timers too (a person can't read a page in a single second, but a person can scroll down that fast)

Comment: The logic is up to you to define based on whatever criteria you choose. You could check to see if the user scrolled to the bottom of the page. You could measure the time spent between scroll position checkpoints to determine if they seem like they're reading or if they just zipped by, you could just use a simple timer that says they were on the page for 2 minutes. Your choice.

Comment: So javascript is doing that...

Comment: Stack Overflow uses jQuery to track your scroll process and animate the panes of the about page. When the last pane is animated (Badges), the page POST-pings `http://stackoverflow.com/about/read` sending the value of `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` as payload data. If you throw [this mess](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/about.js?v=1bcf8bfa82a0) into http://jsbeautifier.org/ and look on line 231, you'll see the POST.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to detect how far a user has scrolled on the page, and if they've scrolled past a certain point (say 80% of the article) you can fire off an AJAX request which logs that the user has scrolled past that point.

Quick example in jQuery:

```
$('body').scroll(function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        // Fire off AJAX request
    }
});
```

Didn't test that, and you'll want to change `1000` to be the amount of pixels until you get to an element in the article so it works for different article lengths.